# Auto transmission slow to engage drive

Tags: opel, astra, pcv-valve

Auto transmission slow to engage drive and gets worse as the car warms up, after 15 minutes and almost refuses to engage drive at all. Reverse is ok though. If drive does engage it can change up through 2nd and onwards but the car does struggle for power. Getting into first gear is the most problematic and once engaged the acceleration is hesitant and a bit jerky. Opel Astra K 1.6 Turbo 2017,160,000kms,new belts, pcv valve also needs replacing.

Comment: Welcome Dean!  What's your specific question?

Comment: Is your vehicle an standard shift?